# Creating tables with SQL Server database in Visual Studio MVC. How to auto generate and increment the Id column?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how to make the `Id` column in a database table to be automatically generated and incremented. Thank you!

[image: create table]

Comment: The question of the post is different from the question of the attached image. Please edit your question in order to facilitate other users

Answer (score 0):

In the design mode, set the column as "Identity".

In code, do:

```
Alter Table "TableName Add Id Int Identity(1,1)
```

MVC:

Put a [Key] annotation before the Id field

```
[Key] [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answering your attached image:

Syntax: IDENTITY [ (seed , increment) ]

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Genres] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
```

Comment: If you want to store only non-Unicode data, use varchar instead nvarchar